# How to beautify xml code in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

Is there a simple way to print an unformated xml string to screen in a ruby on rails application? Something like a xml beautifier?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ruby core REXML::Document has pretty printing:

```
REXML::Document#write( output=$stdout, indent=-1, transitive=false, ie_hack=false )
```

> indent:   An integer. If -1, no
>   indenting will be used; otherwise, the
>   indentation will be twice this number
>   of spaces, and children will be
>   indented an additional amount. For a
>   value of 3, every item will be
>   indented 3 more levels, or 6 more
>   spaces (2 * 3). Defaults to -1

An example:

```
require "rexml/document"

doc = REXML::Document.new "<a><b><c>TExt</c><d /></b><b><d/></b></a>"
out = ""
doc.write(out, 1)
puts out
```

Produces:

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c>
   TExt
  </c>
  <d/>
 </b>
 <b>
  <d/>
 </b>
</a>
```

**EDIT:** Rails has already REXML loaded, so you only have to produce new document and then write the pretty printed XML to some string which then can be embedded in a *<pre>* tag.

Comment: Thanks for this. For a one-liner, I found that this also works: `puts REXML::Document.new(xml_str).write("",1)`

Answer (score 2):

What about the [Nokogiri gem](http://nokogiri.org/)? Here is an [example use](http://vitobotta.com/more-methods-format-beautify-ruby-output-console-logs/).

Comment: do i need the xslt for this method? A very simple method by indentation would be enough for me.

Comment: I've never used this gem personally, but it does look like you would need the transformation.

Comment: It can also be added to `~/.pryrc`, and better replace `puts` calls with `STDOUT.puts`, so it works nicely while in Cucumber, for instance.