# Displaying XML in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

In my Rails app, I'm trying to display the contents of an XML file in a view partial template. I want to display the actual markup of the entire XML file -- tags, properly formatted with indentation, etc. -- not just the text data, or a specific node.

The XML file is located on another server, so first I have to grab the file. Here's my approach so far, which displays the tags but doesn't format them -- it just displays in one unbroken line.

In my controller:

```
@xml_file_path = 'some file path'
@response = Typhoeus::Request.get(@xml_file_path)
```

And in the view template:

```
<%= render :text => @response.body, :content_type => 'application/xml' %>
```

This results in the XML displaying on a single line, like so:

```
<mods:mods><mods:physicalDescription<mods:internetMediaType>image/jpeg</mods:internetMediaType></mods:physicalDescription></mods:mods>
```

But I want it to display to the user with the line breaks and indentation, etc, like so:

```
<mods:mods>
  <mods:physicalDescription>
    <mods:internetMediaType>image/jpeg</mods:internetMediaType>
  </mods:physicalDescription>
</mods:mods>
```

How can I accomplish this? I'm thinking that '`render :text`' is not the right approach here, but not sure what would be better. Any advice appreciated. I'm pretty new to Rails.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to yours:
[How to beautify xml code in rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622269/how-to-beautify-xml-code-in-rails-application)

You can use REXML to create a string of the XML data and then write it using the 'pretty printing' parameter. Then you wrap the string in a `<pre>` tag in the view.