# Pretty print webservice response on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, format

I have to call a webservice but I don't know the format of the response. In any case (xml, json or html) I have to pretty print the response.

For example, if it is a xml I have to indent and show it properly. Same thing if it is a json. I have two problems here:

1. Detecting the format
2. Apply a format depending on the type.

I think that (1) is the most challenging problem.

Any help?

Comment: Parsing to json and making the assumption that if it fails, it will be html, but I am not sure about that approach

Comment: Can you include the code you have used?

Comment: Check the `Content-Type` header of the response. It will probably be something along the lines of `text/html`, `application/json` and `application/xml` (but can be other types).

Comment: Parse response header Content-Type from webservice

Answer (score 3):

As several of the comments have suggested, the http header will contain the content type.

net/http has methods for this: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-head

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'rexml/document'

response = nil
Net::HTTP.start('www.google.com', 80) {|http|
  response = http.get('/index.html')
}
header = response['content-type'].split(';').first  # => "text/html"
body = response.read_body
```

then you can conditionally operate:

```
if header == "text/html"
  puts response.read_body
elsif header == "application/json"
  puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(body))
elsif header == "text/xml"
  xml = REXML::Document.new body
  out = ""
  xml.write(out, 1)
  puts out
end
```

Most of this was pulled form other SO posts:

pretty JSON: [How can I "pretty" format my JSON output in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails)

pretty XML: [How to beautify xml code in rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622269/how-to-beautify-xml-code-in-rails-application)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I finally used:

```
      raw_response = response.body
      response_html = ''

      if response.header['Content-Type'].include? 'application/json'
        tokens = CodeRay.scan(raw_response, :json)
        response_html = tokens.div
      elsif response.header['Content-Type'].include? 'application/xml'
        tokens = CodeRay.scan(raw_response, :xml)
        response_html = tokens.div
      elsif response.header['Content-Type'].include? 'text/html'
        tokens = CodeRay.scan(raw_response, :html)
        response_html = tokens.div
      else
        response_html = '<div>' + raw_response + '</div>'
      end
```

It's using the `coderay` gem.